# Handling multiple objects/types for same command with different parameters

Tags: c++, design-patterns

Here is my problem statement:

1. I have some objects that can be either a single object, or have a tree structure of N depth. So maybe I can have objects A,B,C,D.  Say A,B,C are single level objects while D have 3 children H,I,J. Among H,I,J, H and I are single objects where J again have children and so on.
2. All Objects A,B,C,D,H,I,J have a behavior execute().
3. I have a different class X and all these objects have to use different methods of the SAME INSTANCE OF CLASS X.
4. How do I handle this scenario in a way that:

   - that one function call executes the execute() method for all the objects on the same level as well as down the hierarchy.
   - I dont have to pass the INSTANCE OF X to all the objects.
   - Each object does some different work in its execute() method.

I could think nothing but the composite pattern but my concern was:
      - I dont want to pass the INSTANCE OF X to all the objects in the execute() method parameters but the method needs SAME INSTANCE OF X .

Comment: Which programming language? Decide for one first. Also, what have you tried so far to solve the issue yourself?

Comment: Do I understand you correctly, that X is not supposed to be a singleton? Btw. This is not a C question.

Comment: I think you need some form of code to clarify what you are looking for. Do you want A,B,C,D,H,I,J to all perform their execute() on X? If so then you are going to have a hard time not passing around that X since it is needed everywhere.

Comment: Why is passing around X such a problem for you?

Comment: If you can guarantee that X doesn't change while you are iterating over the nodes calling execute why don't you create a static variable somewhere that stores the current instance of X to act upon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume all the objects with an execute() method have a common base class. I would give the base class a static member which stores a reference or pointer to X, or X itself. You can then call base::SetX() or base::GetX().

(this would also allow you to control access to it with a mutex in the base class, if this ever becomes a multithreaded application).

X sounds like a singleton, so depending on how immutable X is, you may want to just make it global.